# mod_proxy, use wildcards in ProxyPass

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I have a configuration that works for explicitly declared server names:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@myco.com
    ServerName sub0.sub1.myco.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
       Order deny,allow
       Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://sub0.sub1.myco.com:8080/mobilecommerce/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://sub0.sub1.myco.com:8080/mobilecommerce/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain sub0.sub1.myco.com:8080/mobilecommerce sub0.sub1.myco.com
    ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /mobilecommerce /
    ErrorLog "/private/etc/apache2/extra/log/apache2/local-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/etc/apache2/extra/log/apache2/local-acess_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

What this does:

- given an incoming url request with specific sub0, sub1 and domain
  name,
- repeat the long url, only add port number 8080,
- then append with the servlet context: mobilecommerce.

However, I may have multiple sub0 and sub1 created over time.
What I like to do is use wildcard for them,
and still trigger the same rule -- just pass sub0 and sub1 in the translated url.

Is that possible with mod_proxy?
If not, how about mod_jk?

Answer (score 0):

The `ProxyPath` configuration directive does not allow for 'wildcards', but the similar directive `ProxyPassMatch` does.